# How to set the default-directory of compilation in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, compilation, ocaml

I am coding OCaml under Emacs, I have one `makefile` in the working folder, and several sub-folders containing `.ml` files. If I launch `M-x compile` and `make` works fine on a buffer of `makefile`, but does not work on a buffer of a `.ml` file, it gives me an error:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "..." -*-
Compilation started at Fri Jan 27 18:51:35

make -k
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Fri Jan 27 18:51:35
```

It is understandable because the default-directory is sub-folder which does not contain `makefile`. Does anyone know how to set the folder of `makefile` always as the default-directory of compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthias Puech has a [solution](https://syntaxexclamation.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/set-the-root-directory-of-a-project-in-emacs-with-dir-locals-el/) involving a `.dir-local` file in the project root directory:

```
((nil . ((eval . (setq default-directory 
                  (locate-dominating-file buffer-file-name
                   ".dir-locals.el")
)))))
```

It is presumably also possible to use something like: `(shell-command-to-string "git rev-parse --show-toplevel")` as that innermost bit.

Comment: No no no :/ This will break everything, including `find-file`.

Answer (score 22):

You can call `make` with the right arguments:

```
make -C .. -k
```

where `..` is the path to your `Makefile`

Comment: Hah, was looking around for this question, and your answer is the most _obvious_ one in hindsight, I would much prefer it to the _define-your-own-custom-function-with-a-hook-and-change-it-when-you-need-a-different-path_ answers above. Thanks!

Comment: However, build tools will print error messages with paths relative to the directory they're running at, and if that doesn't match the directory of the `*compilation*` buffer, clicking on the file:line in Emacs won't work?

Comment: Aha!  Emacs parses the `make: Entering directory '..'` lines (but only in English locale) so clicking on the file:line links still works!  If not using make, you can manually print them: Compile command: `echo "make: Entering directory '$DIR'"; cd $DIR; ...`

Comment: The parsing is governed by `compilation-directory-matcher` var: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/compile.el?id=emacs-26.1#n597.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10451242/239657.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer since its much more convenient and actually work, at the opposite of the question above.

Comment: @Welgriv I disagree as this answer doesn't answer the question.  The question specifically pertains to Emacs, not Makefile.

Answer (score 9):

You can control this from within emacs by writing a function that (temporarily) sets `default-directory` and calls `compile`.

```
(defun compile-in-parent-directory ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory
          (if (string= (file-name-extension buffer-file-name) "ml")
              (concat default-directory "..")
            default-directory))))
  (call-interactively #'compile))
```

When using `compile-in-parent-directory` all `ml` files will be compiled in the parent directory of where they are.  Of course if they are nested deeper you can change the logic to reflect that.  In fact there is a [version on the EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UsingMakefileFromParentDirectory) which searches parent directories until it finds a makefile.  I found this after I wrote this answer, otherwise I would have just pointed you there.  *sigh*.  The good thing about my method is that it's not specific to `make` so that you can use the same "trick" for other commands.

You can also change the call to compile to be non-interactive if you know exactly what you want the command to be.  This would work particularly well if it's bound to a key in the appropriate mode hook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I have added your code to `.emacs`, but after `M-x`, it can not find `compile-in-parent-directory`

Comment: I have put the code on the EmacsWiki to `.emacs`, pressing `F5` gives me an error: `Symbol's function definition is void: loop`.

Comment: To make function available for interactive call with M-x, you must add (interactive) as first statement to your function.

Comment: Sorry about mine, I have fixed it.  You need to add a (require 'cl) to get the definition of `loop` for the code on EmacsWiki.

Comment: You also need to insert a ' in front of compile --- it needs to be (call-interactively 'compile). I'd edit it, but stack overflow wants at least 6 characters in an edit.

Answer (score 4):

i use a script like this which allows me to run make from any sub-directory (assuming you are in a posix-like environment).  just put this script in your PATH as something like "sub_make.sh" and invoke it the same way you would invoke make:

```
#!/bin/bash

# search for project base
INIT_DIR=`pwd`
while [ "$PWD" != "/" ] ; do
  if [ -e "makefile" ] ; then
    break
  fi

  cd ..
done

if [ ! -e "makefile" ] ; then
  echo "Couldn't find 'makefile'!"
  exit 1
fi

# indicate where we are now
echo "cd "`pwd`
echo make "$@"

# now run make for real
exec make "$@"
```

Comment: you can modify this as follows: `if [ -e "makefile" ] || [ -e "Makefile" ] || [ -e "GNUmakefile" ] ; then` to allow the ther standard makefile names

Answer (score 4):

That's what I have in some of my configs :)

```
(defun* get-closest-pathname (&optional (max-level 3) (file "Makefile"))
  (let* ((root (expand-file-name "/"))
         (level 0)
         (dir (loop
               for d = default-directory then (expand-file-name ".." d)
                 do (setq level (+ level 1))
               if (file-exists-p (expand-file-name file d))
                 return d
               if (> level max-level)
                 return nil
               if (equal d root)
                 return nil)))
    (if dir
        (expand-file-name file dir)
      nil)))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (unless (file-exists-p "Makefile")
              (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
                   (let ((file (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
                         (mkfile (get-closest-pathname)))
                     (if mkfile
                         (progn (format "cd %s; make -f %s"
                            (file-name-directory mkfile) mkfile))
                       (format "%s -c -o %s.o %s %s %s"
                               (or (getenv "CC") "gcc")
                               (file-name-sans-extension file)
                               (or (getenv "CPPFLAGS") "-DDEBUG=9")
                               (or (getenv "CFLAGS") "-ansi -pedantic -Wall -g")
                               file)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I have added your code to `.emacs`, but after launching emacs, it gives me an warning `Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading '~/.emacs': Symbol's function definition is void: defun*`

Comment: hm... try to add (require 'cl) before this functions.

Comment: Thanks Bad_ptr. I used your code to have a command that would execute make command in the main directory in any mode, not just C, also if the buffer was in a directory mode.
I would like it to not do anything though if it did not find the main directory of Makefile. My function unfortunately still execute the make regardless. Could you advice?
(global-set-key [f1]
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
      (compile
                  (let ((mkfile (get-closest-pathname)))
     (if mkfile
      (format "cd %s; make "
       (file-name-directory (get-closest-pathname))))
      
    ))))

Comment: @Ammari try this:`(global-set-key [f1] (lambda ()
                       (interactive)
                        (let ((mkfile (get-closest-pathname)))
                          (if mkfile
                              (compile
                               (format "cd %s; make "
                                       (file-name-directory mkfile)))))))
`

Comment: I rtried it. It still executes make even if it did not fine the Makefile.

Comment: @Ammari ok. I edited `get-closest-pathname` function code. Try this version.

Answer (score 0):

Not a completely general solution w.r.t makefile location, but adding this here for posterity because it solved my particular use-case.

If you use `projectile` and your makefile is always in the root of your project directory, then you can use `projectile-compile-project`.

(In my case, I wanted to lint my project, so calling `(compile "flake8")` would only flake from the current buffer's directory downwards, whereas what I really wanted was linting of the entire project. `projectile-compile-project` achieves this.)