# How to adjust the path that Emacs' compile-goto-error gets from the compilation buffer?

Tags: emacs, compilation, build-system

I am using Emacs 23 and have the following problem:

I run our project's build system from within Emacs like M-x compile -> cd /foo/bar && ./build

The build system now does some magic, "cd"s into some subdirectory for the build process and then gcc throws an error:

../src/somesource.cc:50 error: blablabla

Now the problem is that Emacs won't find that path, because it assumes the compile process started out in /foo/bar, and not in /foo/bar/builddir. So the leading "../" is not working for Emacs, e.g. when running compile-goto-error. Is there a way to tell Emacs to try skipping leading "../"?

Comment: Strangely enough, I'm running into this when building *Emacs*...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best solution might be to change the build system to emit messages when it changes directories.  Emacs looks for

```
Entering directory `...'
... 
Leaving directory `...'
```

(See the `compilation-directory-matcher` variable.  If your build system does emit messages when it changes directories, but they're not in the format Emacs is looking for, you can add new regexps to `compilation-directory-matcher`.)

The other solution is to change `compilation-search-path` (which is a list of directories).

Comment: I didn't know about the "Entering..." functionality of Emacs. That'll probably help!

Comment: @Arne, GNU Make [prints messages in that form](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/_002dw-Option.html) when using recursive makefiles.  That's why Emacs looks for them.

Comment: This solution seems to be what I'm looking for, but I'm unable to edit `compilation-directory-matcher` variable (as you can see here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/21309720/61838). Moreover, the `compilation-search-path` doesn't seems to solve the problem (even when I only need emacs to look for sources in one directory). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: GNU make was recently changed/fixed to use U+0027 instead of U+0060 for the opening quotes and your version of emacs may still be looking for the old U+0060 characters only.  See http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?34530  Try something like: (setq compilation-directory-matcher '("\\(?:Entering\\|Leavin\\(g\\)\\) directory ['`]\\(.+\\)'$" (2 . 1)))

Answer (score 0):

On a few occasions I solved by passing output of the make through sed.

First, debugged it interactively 'Compile command: make | sed 's/x/y/' . And then repackaged it as a custom emacs interactive function.